# AJAX - ASP.Net MVC or jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

It appears that both jQuery and ASP.Net MVC have ways of performing AJAX functions.

Which do you prefer for you AJAX functionality?

Do you typically use one over the other, or does it depend?

Comment: I think you mean Microsoft AJAX, which is included in all ASP.NET MVC projects, along with jQuery.

Comment: why did he get a -1 if he is clearly lost?  don't except everyone to be a code wizard...

Comment: I realize that.  But both ASP.Net MVC and jQuery have helper functions that are unique to each which help with the AJAX calls, right?  Perhaps Razor vs jQuery might be a better way to phrase it than MVC.

Comment: How in the world did that get changed to Microsoft???  That should say MVC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are comparing Microsoft Ajax vs jQuery than there is absolutely no doubt that you should pick jQuery. I have used Microsoft Ajax back in the time when I was doing classic WebForms and with ASP.NET MVC I consider this framework as totally obsolete compared to jQuery. I never use it in any ASP.NET MVC application. Actually in ASP.NET MVC 3 even Microsoft deprectaed it and replaced it with jQuery as the default framework. But even if you are doing ASP.NET MVC 1 or 2 you should use jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

You're comparing apples to oranges. ASP.NET MVC is a web framework, jQuery is a Javascript library.